# Expression resolves to an unused I Value

Tags: swift

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import UserNotifications

class TripDetailViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tripImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tripTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePickertxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfPeopletxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var meetingPoint: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var maxNum: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tripTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var spokenLanguage: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hostNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tripLocation: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hostName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tripDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var touristName: UITextField!

    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    var numbersOfPeoplePicker = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
    let numberOfPeoplePicker = UIPickerView()
    var trip = Trip()

    @IBAction func bookButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "DiscoverAround"
        content.subtitle = "Someone who booked up your trip!"
        content.body = touristName.text!; "Have booked your trip, and they are"; numberOfPeopletxt.text!; "people, in"; datePickertxt.text!;
        content.badge = 1
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

and I'm getting this error:

> "expression resolves to an unused I Value"

on this line:

```
content.body = touristName.text!; "Have booked your trip, and they are"; numberOfPeopletxt.text!; "people, in"; datePickertxt.text!;
```

Comment: The semicolon (`;`) indicates that the current statement has ended and a new statement is beginning. That line has several unconnected statements.

Comment: I really wonder what you think what that assignment does.

Answer (score 2):

You are not formatting the text correctly. If you want to concatenate strings, you should do it like this:

```
content.body = "\(touristName.text!) Have booked your trip, and they are \(numberOfPeopletxt.text!) people, in \(datePickertxt.text!)"
```

If you are not sure that the field's values are nil or not, you should check it before or provide a default value to them:

```
if let tourist = touristName.text,
    let numberOfPeople = numberOfPeopletxt.text,
    let datePicker = datePickertxt.text {
    content.body = "\(tourist) Have booked your trip, and they are \(numberOfPeople) people, in \(datePicker)"
}
```

or

```
content.body = "\(touristName.text ?? "Nobody") Have booked your trip, and they are \(numberOfPeopletxt.text ?? "0") people, in \(datePickertxt.text ?? "nowhere")"
```

Comment: You haven't unwrapped the `Optional` values returned by the `text` properties so this code might not work as intended, unwrap them properly before using them.

Comment: Ok so now you've force unwrapped them, if they return `nil` then you'll have a runtime error. That's not the proper way to handle unwrapping an `Optional`, test it properly when you unwrap it.

Comment: @ColGraff In normal circumstances, a `UITextField`'s text value will never be nil, unless a direct modification in the value has happened, that's why I included force unwrapping.

Comment: "Proper way" is subjective; there are definitely instances where force unwrapping is okay.

Comment: This is true but it's still an unsafe assumption to make. There are circumstances where force unwrapping is the way to go but most times it's simple enough to test and be safe.

Comment: You should use `!` or `??`, not both.

Comment: It was just a typo, sorry. Fixed.